# use jquery 1.6 with script for 1.9

Tags: jquery

I am using a script designed for jQuery 1.9.1 and has this line:

```
 jQuery('.mean-expand').on("click",function(e){
```

I am working on a site that uses jQuery 1.6.2 and I get the error, referring to the code above:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function
```

Is there any way of changing the function so it will work with jQuery 1.6?

Edit - I do not want to upgrade jQuery because there are some scripts running that fail with later jQuery, and I find the later jQuerys to be bigger files.

Comment: Why not upgrading jQuery then???

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. If you need to know what to replace it with, the answer is [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), depending on the context.

Comment: change `.on` for `.bind`

Comment: @Karl can you make this an answer?  It is the most simple.  Yes I know it tells me the error that 1.6 does not recognise on but I dont know what to switch it with. Thank you for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.on` is a new method that regroup the functionalities of `.bind()` and `.live()`, you should be able the get your code working with one of those.

From what i see, you are using direct binding (if you need more information on direct binding, check out the jQuery documentation of the `.on()` method), `.bind` is what you need.

Change you `.on()` to `.bind()`:

```
jQuery('.mean-expand').bind("click",function(e){...});
```

Comment: the other answers work great as well, but this is the most simple and easiest to implement answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since that particular statement is not using delegated event handlers, you could simple use this

```
jQuery('.mean-expand').click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add 1.9.x too if you want to keep jquery 1.6.x ;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.x.js"></script>
```

And then,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j_1_9_x = $.noConflict(true);

(function($){ 
   // Write jquery 1.9.x related code here 
   $('.mean-expand').on("click", function(e){ ...
}(j_1_9_x ));

</script>
```

Or you can update your function as;

```
jQuery('.mean-expand').click(function(){...
```

in order to make it run with 1.6.x

Comment: yes this works - thanks.  But I do find switching .on for .bind is a more simple answer.  Although this one is cleaner code taking the click out of the brackets...

Comment: @Jon I was reading other answers and saw your comment here. Yes `.click()` is cleaner, but it is less performant. I just think it is important to mention it : click is the shorthand of `.on('click', fn)` or `.bind('click')` in your case.

Comment: `.on()` and `.bind()` actually same but `.on()` also does event delegation, that is why I preferred it